Conditionally enable Rust API only for `T = dyn Trait` type arguments
I have the following struct:
struct Struct<T: ?Sized = DefaultType> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Struct<T>
where
    T: ?Sized + MaybeAnotherBound,
{
    fn retrieve(&self) -> &T { ... }
}

The idea here is that a user would provide a trait object for T, for example dyn Trait.
If nothing is provided, DefaultType will be used.
Is it possible to restrict the impl in a way that the retrieve() function is only enabled if T is explicitly provided, i.e. actually a dyn Trait trait object? The freedom I see here is in choosing DefaultType, as well as requiring T bounds on the impl block.
What I've tried so far:

T: Any as a trait bound, so that it would exclude DefaultType but include dyn Trait type arguments. The Any trait seems to be implemented for all types that don't contain (non-static) lifetimes. But how could I possibly choose a DefaultType with lifetimes?
Use the auto traits. Unfortunately, it looks like all of them (Send, Sync, Unpin, UnwindSafe, RefUnwindSafe) are not implemented for trait objects, so I cannot conditionally enable the latter.

Any other ideas how I can selectively enable this? Specialization or nightly features are not an option.

Edit: why I need this
The Struct<T> type above represents a pointer to an object managed in C (via FFI). This can:

either be opaque: no type arguments given, i.e. T=DefaultType
or it can optionally implement some known Rust traits: Struct<dyn MyTrait>, which allows retrieve() to exposed the trait's functionality.

I previously had two separate types here, but due to large API surface and easier generic programming, it would be nice to combine it in a single type with an optional generic parameter.

It seems your striving very far from idiomatic Rust, so now you're stuck trying to do something that is impossible in Rust. This question is an XY problem: tell us what you were trying to do, and we can help you finding out a more appropriate design.

impl Struct<dyn MaybeAnotherBound> {} ?

@jthulhu Good point, I added the description around my use case as an edit. I'm aware there are different solutions (like 2 separate structs), my question is specifically tailored around recognizing dyn Trait generic arguments.

@ChrisB This unfortunately doesn't work, as MaybeAnotherBound can be specified by the user, and the library doesn't know about it. That's why I'd need a generic approach.

@TheOperator: What is the problem with just always enabling the retrieve method?

@ChrisB the method doesn't make sense when T is not a dyn Trait object. It doesn't show up in IDE completions and people can't accidentally call it.

Two separate types seem like the correct approach here. You can mitigate the drawbacks in other ways (e.g. macros).
